# What in machine configuration can prevent booting from iso

Tags: boot, uefi, iso, bios

Ran into a really weird issue recently
I have an ISO I want to install on my server. On all machines I had before it ran smoothly. Now I have got another one and it doesn't detect the ISO when I mount it as virtual media.
First I thought the ISO was a problem (since it is a custom one), so I tried the oficial CentOS 8 ISO and it works ok, I was able to install it.
Also, as I have mentioned, this ISO works fine on other machines.
Another detail is that the new machine runs UEFI with Legacy Mode not being supported.
So it looks like it is some combination of the ISO configurations and UEFI settings which prevents ISO from being loaded.
However, I have done a lot of research on the Internet and haven't found anything similar.
Now my question is what can be such a combination? In which direction should I look?

Comment: Is secure boot disabled? A custom ISO most likely is not properly signed where vanilla CentOS8 should be.

Comment: Yes, secure boot is disabled. If there is a problem with signature, then how am I able to install it on different machines?

Comment: Some firmwares don't grok _dual_ signature, I've witnessed that a few years ago (MSFT+distro wouldn't work, MSFT only would).

Comment: Hmm, that's and interesting idea. How can I check that the signature is dual? The iso was not assembled by me, so is there some software i can use?